# В чём разница между многопоточностью и мультипроцессностью?

Tags: многопоточность

Начинаю изучать параллелизм, но не очень понимаю в чём различие между многопоточностью и мультипроцессностью.

В Python есть два класса для этого: `threading.Thread`, `multiprocessing.Process`. Видимо первый предназначен для создания потоков, а второй для процессов.

**Но в чем поток отличается от процесса?**

Comment: мультипроцессорность и мультипроцессность - немного разные вещи :-)

Comment: @Grundy поправил, спасибо.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-multiprocessing-and-multithreading/

Comment: @Эникейщик спасибо, но всё же понятнее будет если кто-то напишет ответ, и на русском понятнее, и у нас принято что-бы вопрос был с ответом.

Comment: если отвечать в лоб на вопрос _чём же разница?_ - то ответ содержится в вопросе _первый предназначен для создания **потоков**, а второй - для **процессов**_. Хочешь ли ты свести свой вопрос к "Чем поток отличается от процесса"?

Comment: @Grundy вопрос на который вы сослались как дубликат, другой. Я изменил свой вопрос. Вы можете закрывать вопросы единолично, поэтому он закрылся сразу, я даже ничего сделать не могу.

Comment: @nchistov, в чем отличие твоего вопрос от вопроса дубликата? В принятом ответе в явном виде содержится ответ на твой вопрос, как до редактирования, так и после.

Comment: @nchistov ну переведите и напишите. Будет и на русском и вопрос с ответом ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Upd. А, уже закрыт как дубликат. Ну ладно тогда.

Comment: imho основное отличие процесса от потока в том, что у каждого процесса свое виртуальное адресное пространство, а у всех потоков оно одно и то же. Т.е. одинаковые адреса (имеется в виду "обычный" (т.е. не из  shared области памяти) адрес) в разных процессах ссылаются на разные ячейки в физической памяти, а одинаковые адреса в разных потоках на одни и те же ячейки. Соответственно, потоки всегда разделяют общую для них таблицу файлов (с текущим указателем позиции чтения-записи), а у процессов такая таблица у каждого своя. Примерно то же и с другими ресурсами. Далее очевидно ...